# I need to add headers to file , but I am losing first row of data after using `df.columns` in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas.
My txt file does not have headers.
Hence I am adding it explicitly.
However after using `df.columns`, I am losing the top row of data, how can I avoid losing the top row/ first row ?

**Code**:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('ABC.txt',sep = '\t')
headers =  ['name', 'age', 'group']
df1.columns = headers
df1.to_csv('newABC.txt', sep = '\t')
```

**Input**:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qiyg4.png)

**Output**:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foZOg.png)

**Expected Output**:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojCP3.png)

Comment: does not help me

Comment: Do you try `df1 = pd.read_csv('ABC.txt',sep = '\t', header=None)` ?